# Where is my Ubuntu One ribbon?

Tags: ubuntu-one, python, nautilus-elementary

I'm not seeing the Ubuntu One ribbon in Nautilus-Elementary. I have the nautilus-terminal extension as well, so I don't know if they don't work together.

I tried running nautilus from the terminal (for a separate issue), and I think I might be onto something. It seems the Ubuntu One ribbon is not finding something (it had an exception). I got the NE-Terminal working again by deleting the gconf directory for Nautilus.

Comment: You can't turn it on by *right-click -> Show Ribbon in Some Folders* ?

Comment: @DoR no. In fact the nautilus terminal ribbon disappeared as well yesterday for no apparent reason.

Comment: This is probably too localized as U1 supports Nautilus, not nautilus-elementary.

Comment: @Jorge I had checked the commandline output and it apparently was just a problem with either U1 itself or another plugin, because it complained about some version numbers or something (was a python traceback) and after some upgrades etc, it stopped. I don't remember now the specific details though :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what fixed it, but the ribbon is back!

It was most likely an update, or just the fact that I removed some extra nautilus plugins.